# NDVI calculation of Sentinel-2 images results in very different values

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I am trying to calculate the NDVI from Sentinel-2 2LA images from different years in order to observe the change in vegetation over time. The images are from 2020, 2021 and 2022 all from the same month (dec). When calculating the NDVI, the results are very different from another. For example, the result for 2021 gives me (what I think) the correct result with values from -1 to 0.999181. However, the result from 2020 gives me values from -0.467836 to 0.999353. When I reclassify the two results, there is a huge difference and makes the two images incomparable (see pictures)

[image]

[image]

I am calculating the NDVI using the raster calculator in QGIS.

Comment: The computed values with different images *ought* to be different. What's the problem?

Comment: What I mean is that there is not such a big change in vegetation in that year. For example the dark green parts in the 2021 image are dense forest, so it should be the same for 2020 since there was no change in vegetation (I checked with google earth images).

Comment: NDVI uses near infrared, does it not? Couldn't it show drought stress not visible in RGB? Isn't that the point of doing year-on-year comparisons?

Comment: "In general, NDVI values range from -1.0 to 1.0, with negative values indicating clouds and water, positive values near zero indicating bare soil, and higher positive values of NDVI ranging from sparse vegetation (0.1 - 0.5) to dense green vegetation (0.6 and above)." Source: https://ipad.fas.usda.gov/cropexplorer/Definitions/spotveg.htm.
If you disregard negative values, it seems the numbers you got are reasonable. Why are you reclassifying them? Try to disregard negative values, and compare values between 0 to 1.